Find largest size of valid combination by partitioning
Let $A$ be a finite set, and let $P(a,b)$ be a predicate.
Let $B$ be the set of all possible subset of $A$ that all pair of elements of the subset match the predicate.
$B = \{ X | X \subset A \wedge (\forall a \in X)(\forall b \in X)P(a,b)  \}$
For the sake of explanation, let $f(G)$ be the function that define the set of subsets in the above manner, so
$f(G) = \{ X | X \subset G \wedge (\forall a \in X)(\forall b \in X)P(a,b)  \}$
so $B = f(A)$ in this case. Let's call $f(G)$ the set of all "valid" subsets.
and let $m(H)$ be the largest set in $H$
My question is, if B could be partitioned into smaller set $B_1, B_2, ..., B_n$, which $P(a,b)$ holds true if $a$ and $b$ are not from the same partition, is it true that size of the largest set in B will be the sum of the size of largest valid subset of each partition? In the other words, is it true that $|m(B)| = |m(f(B_1))|+|m(f(B_2))|+...+|m(f(B_n))|$?
A specific example for the above is that to find the largest size of valid subset of a range of integer which the difference of all pairs are not $N$. If we partition the said range to multiple partitions in which the difference of any pair between each partition is not equal to N, and find the largest possible valid subset of each partition, we can come up with the largest size by summing all those largest size of each partition?
Feel free to edit title or the content. I am very new to this.
